# What does @@@ mean in Dynamics-NAV Text Constants

Tags: dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I have noticed that in Dynamics NAV 2013 that some TextConsts have started using @@@ as the language code.

For example in Codeunit 12:

```
PurchaseAlreadyExistsErr@1003 : TextConst '@@@="%1 = Document Type;
```

What does @@@ mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're there as translation comments. My friend Jan Hoek his written a nice blog post on this: http://mibuso.com/blogs/zenandtheartofcsidedevelopment/category/textconstants/.
So 'help yourself' ;-)